# switching between autocompletion and character-by-character entry in an ido path

Tags: emacs

I use ido in Emacs. Sometimes, when I have a path open in the minibuffer (for example, when I've executed C-x C-f), I'd like to edit the path by removing only the last character of a directory whose name I've partially completed. However, the backspace key always backs up a full directory level. I can use an additional C-f (provided that my path is specified only up to the boundary between one directory and another) to switch over to character-by-character entry, which will let me either back up or type additional characters. However, at this point, I have lost the ability to see the contents of the directory that begin with the sequence I've typed. Is there a way, once I've typed a partial path in "C-f mode", to switch back into autocompletion mode so that I can see all the possibilities that begin with my partial path?

Comment: That sounds super complicated.  Have a look at helm https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm .  Helm is so much better for seeing a big listing of long strings (i.e. filenames).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe helm is great, but its documentation is not. Unless the landing page or wiki gives me a basic idea of what it offers, there's no reason for me to try it, especially since installation is nontrivial, particularly on Windows. Geez, people. If you're going to spend months of your life developing a software package, then spend half a day coming up with a nontrivial overview. "Just install it and you'll love it" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Helm is in melpa, which means it is trivial to install (If you haven't set up package.el, you obviously have to do that first.  It's not hard.  If you aren't using package.el, you're missing out.).  Configuration may be a different matter, but it's certainly easy to install and play with.  I don't see what's wrong with Helm's Readme, either.  It gives a couple sentence description, and there's a link to a wiki page with more in-depth info.

Comment: The initial description says exactly this much: "Helm is incremental completion and selection narrowing framework for Emacs. It will help steer you in the right direction when you're looking for stuff in Emacs (like buffers, files, etc)." It also mentions that it's a successor to anything.el. That's it. No further description. No screenshots or simulated screenshots. The wiki page doesn't give a description of helm, either. It tells you that you can use C-h m to get detailed help. So now an overview has been deferred at least twice!

Comment: Compare it to the [ido documentation](http://www.cua.dk/ido.html), for instance. Now **there's** a page that tells you what you can expect **before** you install the package.

Comment: For what it's worth, the melpa page is even worse. Go to its [home page](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) and you find nothing but this at the top of the page: "MELPA or Milkypostman’s ELPA or Milkypostman’s Experimental Lisp Package Repository if you’re not into the whole brevity thing." Nothing that says what the darn thing does, or how to use it, or whether it has anything to do with package.el. That's treated as engineer lore that I presume is supposed to be passed around the campfire. The bar that engineers set themselves for documentation is really, really low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the input with <kbd>C-e</kbd> then switch back with <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the C-e has turned off ido autocompletion persistently. Is there a way I can get the old behavior to come back? The C-e shortcut doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere that I see on the web, much less how to reverse it.

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment: When I type C-x C-f, I only see directories, not files, listed as possibilities. Previously, I used to see files (at least some of them, with the remainder indicated by "...") in addition to directories at this point. When I start typing, for example, "cpp", I start seeing the files with ".cpp" extensions. But previously, I didn't need to type anything in order to see at least some of the files.